# Is there a way to import a CSV to Oracle DB with automatic table creation? Using commando line

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql, import

I'm looking for a way to import a CSV to Oracle DB without manual table creation before the import. Does somebody know a solution?
Thats the code I used with a predefined table, it's part of a .ctl-File and works with the SQL Loader. Is it maybe possible to modify it to solve the problem?

```
load data
infile 'D:/random.csv'
into table konten
fields terminated by ';'
(kontonummer,firmenname,inhaber,rechtsform,email,kontostand)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give csv2db a try.

The *generate* option will create the table for you.

```
# https://github.com/csv2db/csv2db

# drop user
echo 'drop user csvdata cascade;' | sqlplus -S system/oracle@localhost:1521/XEPDB1

# create user and grant privileges
sqlplus -S system/oracle@localhost:1521/XEPDB1 <<EOF
create user csvdata identified by load default tablespace USERS temporary tablespace TEMP quota unlimited on USERS;
grant create session, resource to csvdata;
EOF

# generate DDL
time csv2db generate --file=movies.csv --table=MOVIES | sed 's/1000/4000/' \
| sqlplus -S csvdata/load@localhost:1521/XEPDB1

# load data
time csv2db load --user=csvdata --password=load --host=localhost --port=1521 --dbname=XEPDB1 \
       --separator=',' --table=MOVIES --directpath \
       --file=movies.csv

# what do we have?
echo 'select count(*) from movies;' | sqlplus -S csvdata/load@localhost:1521/XEPDB1
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using ***read_csv*** function of ***pandas*** which is a library of ***python*** language to be used for data manipulation and analysis such as

```py
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

user    = 'hr'
password = 'hr'
host    = '192.168.56.102'
port    = '1521'
dbname  = 'myOracleDB'

con = cx_Oracle.connect(user, password, host+':'+port+'/'+dbname)
cur = con.cursor()
tab_name = 'konten'
cur.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_tables WHERE table_name = UPPER(:1) ',[tab_name])       
exs = cur.fetchone()[0]
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\\random.csv')
col=df.columns[0].split(";")
crt=""
for k in col:
    crt += ''.join(k)+' VARCHAR2(4000),'

if int(exs) == 0:
    crt = 'CREATE TABLE '+tab_name+' ('+crt.rstrip(",")+')'
    cur.execute(crt)

vrs=""
for i in range(0,len(col)):
    vrs+= ':'+str(i+1)+','

cols=[]
sql = 'INSERT INTO '+tab_name+' VALUES('+vrs.rstrip(",")+')'
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    cols.append(df.values[i][0].split(";"))
cur.executemany(sql,cols)
con.commit()
cur.close
```

Comment: The OP should also review the cx_Oracle doc on batch loading https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html